# What the purpose of Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

***"TypeScript lets you write JavaScript the way you really want to.
TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript.
Any browser. Any host. Any OS. Open Source."***

According to it,

- `Typescript` is created just to ease the `JavaScript` development.

  - Am I right ? or it has something more to offer ?
- Can in use `<script type="typescript" >` in html pages ?
- Is it compatible with  all the modern browsers ?

I was looking for these answers but the most of the basic thread related to `TypeScript` are closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Typescript is create just to ease the javaScript development. Am i right ?

Yes, Typescript offers several syntactical features that are either (1) not present in JavaScript, or (2) part of a future JavaScript proposal and not supported by most browsers.

CoffeeScript exists for a similar reason, except that its syntax is quite different from JavaScript and it does not attempt to be a superset of JavaScript.

> or it has something more to offer ?

What else would you have in mind?

> can in use  in html pages ? is it compatible with all the modern browsers ?

It is possible to compile and run TypeScript within a web page, though the browser will not do this for you automatically. [typescript-compile](https://github.com/niutech/typescript-compile) provides the ability to do this, but there are big performance drawbacks to doing so.

Typically, one would compile TypeScript into JavaScript ahead of time and include the compiled JavaScript in a page. You can set up a build process to do this, and ASP.NET projects have built-in functionality to do Typescript -> JavaScript compilation without any manual steps.

Comment: So it's like a syntactic sugar for JavaScript which generates pure JavaScript on compilation.

Comment: @VinodSrivastav Yes, basically. The central point of TypeScript is that it is designed to use static typing and compile-time type checking, while JavaScript uses dynamic typing throughout.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @JLRishe from above but I wanted to point out a very important (at least for me) benefit from TypeScript.

With the Type annotations (eg: foo: string; bar: number and :ClassName) I can safely change something with refactor->rename knowing that TypeScript will change everything where it is used. So because of the annotations the tooling knows where you use objects and can help you with "go to definition", "find all references", "refactor->rename" making big changes in very large projects a lot easier and less dangerous.

Also language features like `classes`, `modules`, `generics` make it easier to create large apps!

Comment: @VinodSravastav, I know some IDE's can infer it pretty good and some others require some jsdoc annotations to make it work reliable but to my knowledge they don't make it mandatory (which TypeScript with --noimplicitany can). So while you are right it is possible with plain javascript, I find it a lot better with TypeScript. (and I did use WebStorm ;))